# Populating a Spinner with a JSON Array

Tags: java, android, json, spinner

I have the following code populating a spinner,

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(new String(buffer));
JSONArray myUsers = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("GetBusNamesResult");

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapter.add("Select a Buseness...");

for (int i = 0; i < myUsers.length(); ++i)
{
    //String jsonStr = myUsers.getString(i);
    //JSONObject myJsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    //adapter.add(myJsonObj.getString("BusName"));
    adapter.add(myUsers.getString(i));
}

userSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
userSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

With this JSON object,

```
{"GetBusNamesResult":[{"BusName":"Fred Camping","BusPhone":"0434943743"},{"BusName":"Joe's Carpets","BusPhone":"1234687965"}]}
```

But it displays the whole list for each record in the spinner like this,

```
{“BusName”:”Joe”,”BusPhone”:”1234567890”}
```

How can I fix that? I am able to put just the username into the spinner with the commented out code above but then get no return values.

Also is that returned JSON called an “Array List”???

Cheers,

Mike.

Comment: @user903601 can u add whole code of spinner..

Comment: @user903601 can u add whole code of spinner..new String(buffer)); what is buffer here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change;

```
adapter.add(myUsers.getString(i));
```

to

```
adpater.add(myUsers.getJSONObject(i).getString("BusName");
```

To retrieve the bus phone once the bus name has been selected, store your bus name and bus phone values in a map as well. That way, when the bus name is selected, you can populate your widgets with the info from the map.

Comment: That seems to give me the same result as the commented out code above, I get no return results because the string is stripped back to just the Business Name. I need the selected value to then populate two variables.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: When I use you code or the code I’ve //commented out in my code at the top the value of BusName, in my example “Fred Camping” is input into the spinner but I lose the value of BusPhone completely. What I need is that when an item is selected from the spinner, the retrieved name value pair are split into two variables and sent off to manipulate a button. BusName becomes the button text and BusPhone is used to send a text when the button is clicked. That part works fine but the text in the spinner looks like: {“BusName”:”Fred Camping”,”BusPhone”:”1234567890”} and not just “Fred Camping”.

Comment: Edited my response to address your issue.

Comment: Sorry Kurtis, I missed your update above, I thought it would have to work something like that but was not sure. Cheers, Mike.

Comment: I kind of understand what has to done but have no idea how to do it. Do you know of a tutorial that will show me how to do this???

Comment: For creating maps? I'm sure the java documentation can show you how.